# Detect new version of bundle in Angular application deployed in production

Tags: angular, spring-boot, apache2, production-environment, http-caching

I have developed an application with a front in Angular (4.x) and a back in SpringBoot (fat jar).
The angular application is hosted in production on an http apache server (2.2.x).
The application is bundled with ng-cli and the production profile.

I love the local navigation without request the server but I want to know how to detect that a bundle change in the apache when I deploy a new version and the users are still connected to the application in their browsers.

If a hit CTRL+F5 it's ok but if I navigate with the routes the new files aren't served.

How I detect a change of bundled files (css, js, html) on the server ?

Hope I am quite clear !

Comment: I'm assuming you have only a _single_ [module](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules) in your application, then? Also, how is your server-side cache configured?